# Why do my SATA devices show up under /proc/scsi/scsi?

Tags: linux, sata, scsi, devices

I have 3 SATA devices on my system. They show up under `/proc/scsi/scsi`, although these are not SCSI devices. Why do my SATA devices show up under the SCSI directory?

```
$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD2500AAJS-6 Rev: 01.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: TSSTcorp Model: CDDVDW TS-H653Z  Rev: 4303
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi4 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST3320620AS      Rev: 3.AA
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They show up as SCSI devices because the drivers speak [SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) to the next kernel layer (the generic disk driver). This isn't actually true of all [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) drivers on all kernel versions with all kernel compile-time configurations, but it's common. Even [PATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) devices can appear as SCSI at that level (again, that depends on the kernel version and kernel compile-time configuration, as well as whether the `ide-scsi` module is used).

It doesn't really matter whether the driver speaks SCSI to the physical device. Often, it does. [ATAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#ATAPI), used for talking to PATA/SATA optical drives and other devices, is a SCSI-based protocol encapsulation. However, PATA/SATA disks don't use ATAPI. The [libata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibATA) set of drivers also includes a [translator](http://www.t10.org/drafts.htm#sat3) between the ATA command set and SCSI so that you can place PATA/SATA disks under the umbrella of the SCSI subsystem. The separate ide interface inside the kernel is more of a historical survivance.

You'll notice that [USB disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class) also appear as SCSI, for the same reason (and they speak SCSI too on the USB bus). The same goes for [Firewire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1394_interface).

Comment: Do many IDE devices speak SCSI, and do they show up under `/proc/scsi`? On another system, I have an IDE DVD drive which is listed under `/proc/ide/hdb/model`.

Comment: @Stefan: All non-ancient IDE hardware devices speak SCSI to the controller. All (I think) IDE drivers can speak SCSI (or maybe I should say look SCSI) to the generic disk layer if compiled accordingly, but they (and a few SATA drivers) can also look like IDE.

Comment: Gilles, can you please precise the layers (from hw to Linux upper layers)? I guess we have something like: device (physical drive), SATA host controller (PHY HBA), Low level driver (receiving SCSI commands, speaking to PHY HBA), SCSI-core midlayer (scsi_mod.ko), libata OR scsi-disk-driver (sd_mod.ko), block (available through /dev/sdX). Do you agree?

Comment: I meant "can you please *specify*"...

Comment: Does it mean the protocol which is used betwenn the mainboard and the drive is SCSI?

Comment: @somega Not necessarily. It only means that part of the software/firmware stack uses (a subset of) the SCSI data protocol.

Comment: So when I run "cat /dev/sr0" SCSI commands are translated to AHCI and then send to the SATA device? (If the drive talks AHCI)