# SATA: what linux kernel drivers are needed for basic support?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, sata

I am looking for the basic kernel drivers to enable SATA support.

I have a Braswell (Intel SoC) setup and I would like to reduce the number of kernel drivers to a minimum. Does SATA support need the ATA drivers ? What about the SCSI drivers ? Or Device Mapper Support (from the RAID menu) ? It seems there is more than 10 different generic drivers needed to support SATA besides the manufacturer's driver.

I am using the linux kernel 4.4 and I could not find much information in the Documentation. It seems that the ATA, SATA and SCSI menuconfig options are scattered across multiple sections.

I guess the most important one is the `libata` driver, but it is unclear for me if they need the ATA or SCSI drivers

```
Device Drivers  --->
    Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers (libata)   --->
```

I searched the subject but didn't find a clear answer. I liked this answer about the historical perspective of ATA and SCSI and how they can [talk to each other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144561/in-what-sense-does-sata-talk-scsi-how-much-is-shared-between-scsi-and-ata).

Also, would there be any major difference when enabling SATA for another SoC, like an ARM SoC, beside the vendor specific driver ? An ideal answer would refer to the specific options in menuconfig !

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

The kernel layers are a bit complex, and I can't give you a complete picture. Today, nearly all storage devices use some kind of SCSI commands (which why they show up as `/dev/sdX` instead of `/dev/hdX`), though that can be transported over different mechanisms (ATA packets, or USB, or others). So you need at least:

- The SATA driver for your particular hardware (possibly several modules, e.g. `libahci`)
- The generic ATA layer (possibly several modules, including `libata`)
- The generic SCSI layer, at least for the kind of storage devices you use (definitely several modules, including `scsi_mod`).

I *think* the kernel should be able to figure out the minimal dependencies itself in `menuconfig`: If you first disable everything, and then enable only the bottom driver (hardware specific) and the top driver (SCSI disk, `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD`, module `sd_mod`) you'll *likely* end up with a pretty minimal workable configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, this is quite the picture that I had in mind: SATA modules depend on the basic ATA and SCSI modules. I also read that the eveolution of ATA to SATA brought more protocols to the ATA ecosystem (SFF, BMDMA, etc). I will try disabling these legacy modules and see how it works with this Braswell Soc.

Comment: I will accept your answer. Note that the SATA driver in `menuconfig` does not automatically select the necessary `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD`.

Comment: That's why I said bottom *and* top driver (which is `sd_mod`).